# Functionality of rnorm with numpy.random.normal

Tags: python, r, numpy

For some vector m (of length N) of numbers in R we can write

```
rnorm(N, mean = m, sd = 1)
```

and this will give a vector of length N where each element will be a sample for a normal distribution centred at the different elements of m. My question is, is it possible to do the same easily with numpy? As far as I can tell numpy.random.normal() requires the *loc* to be the same for all the elements. The point is that I want a random vector with different means.

Also while writing this, would it work to sample from a standard normal distribution and transform this sample? That would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do is random sampling at center `0` then move the sample:

```
m, N = np.array([1,2,3]), 1000

np.random.seed(42)
samples = np.random.randn(N,len(m)) + m
```

Comment: Thank you. How would you do something similar for probability densities? e.g the functionality of dnorm(y, mean = m)

Comment: that's a second question, you're supposed to ask only one question ... but the answer is, scale first (calculate `(x-mean)/sd`, then compute the prob density for the standard normal